# Why do I get Invalid literal for int() exception error when running basic django query?

Tags: django, models

A simple django query is not working and I am wondering why

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text, self.author, self.pub_date)
```

In the django shell or in my views I have tried

```
itemstosell = Entry.objects.get(author=username)[:4]
```

which results in:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'john'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because author is a foreign key and as such will be a reference to the primary key on the user model which is likely to be an integer. Your ought to do

```
itemstosell = Entry.objects.get(author__username=username)[:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, "get" method is only return 1 result. We use it like this:
itemstosell = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)

"filter" method can return a QuerySet, if you want to use "(author__username=username)[:4]" as an option, you should use this style:
itemstosell = Entry.objects.filter(author__username=username)[:4]

Comment: OH, I UNDERSTAND, I think your problem is that you did not set the "__str__" method in  "AUTH_USER_MODEL", So, django return the primary key which could be a number "id".  I think you should change your "AUTH_USER_MODEL", add the content as below:  
def __str__(self):
    return self.username